# Events not registering after replaceWith

Tags: jquery, events, dom

When I `replaceWith` an element to bring one out of the DOM, then `replaceWith` it back in, events registered to it do not fire.  I need to events to remain intact.

Here's my Javascript:

```
var replacement = $(document.createElement('span'));
var original = $(this).replaceWith(replacement);

replacement
    .css('background-color', 'green')
    .text('replacement for ' + $(this).text())
    .click(function() {
        replacement.replaceWith(original);
    });
```

[**Live demo**](http://liranuna.com/strager/b/replace-with.html)

In the demo, when you click an element, it is replaced with another element using `replaceWith`.  When you click the new element, that is replaced with the original element using `replaceWith`.  However, the click handler does not work any more (where I would think it should).

Comment: Did you end up using the event reattachment, or were you ever able to get Live events to work? I am doing the exact same thing, and would love to learn from your experience.

Comment: @Erick T, I'm sorry, but I honestly cannot remember.  I asked this question almost two years ago.  I think using `$.fn.live` didn't work because I was dealing with actual elements, not a selector.  (`$.fn.delegate` (which didn't exist then) may work for you as a `live` alternative.)  Because of the answer I selected, I assume I did end up re-attaching the event handler.  You may try deep cloning the element as well (which IIRC may keep event handlers in the latest jQuery).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because when you replace the original element, events bound to it are removed. You'll need to re-attach the `click` event handler on `original` after the call to `replacement.replaceWith(original)`:

```
$(function() 
{   
   function replace() 
   {
      var replacement = $(document.createElement('span'));
      var original = $(this).replaceWith(replacement);

      replacement
         .css('background-color', 'green')
         .text('replacement for ' + $(this).text())
         .click(function() 
         {
            replacement.replaceWith(original);
            original.click(replace);
         });
   }

   $('.x').click(replace);
});
```

Comment: I wish there were an automatic/elegant way of doing this.  I guess this solution will have to do.

Comment: @strager: You could try Matt's live events suggestion, or implement a targeted version for your own purposes. There are serious (and unpleasant) side-effects in *certain browsers* if you fail to detach events from detached elements, so you really do want it to work this way.

Comment: This does not make sense. Elements can have events without being attached to the DOM, so why would removing them from the DOM remove the events? Must be some performance specific decisions, well well...

Comment: I would also point you to this alternative code to replace elements without losing the bound events:http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13400#comment:10

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**: `live()` and `bind()` have been deprecated, in favour of [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

You can use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) events, this is your new code:

```
$(function() {
$('.x').live('click', function() {
    var replacement = $(document.createElement('span'));
    var original = $(this).replaceWith(replacement);

    replacement
        .css('background-color', 'green')
        .text('replacement for ' + $(this).text())
        .bind('click', function() {
            replacement.replaceWith(original);
        });
});
});
```

-Live event works with jQuery 1.3 and upper.

-if you want to stop the live propagation use [die()](http://api.jquery.com/die/) function.

Answer (score 3):

[live events](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) are what you are looking for

Comment: May be what I need.  I'll look into it.