# Running functions on replaced content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I had guessed that this code would work. But the JS doesn't alert anything. **What is the best way to run functions on replaced content?** It is a simple code as you can see, if you work with jquery. I need answers only if you have suggestions.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="add" name="sub">Add</button> 

<script>
$(document).on('click',"#add",function(){
$( this ).replaceWith("<button type='button' id='sub'> Alert </button>");
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#sub").click(function()
{
alert("Does it alert?");
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770308/events-not-registering-after-replacewith

Comment: Your last code section should follow the selection format as in the first script section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add via

```
$(document).on('click', '#sub', function() { })
```

**Example**

```js
$(document).on('click',"#add", function() {
    $( this ).replaceWith("<button type='button' id='sub'> Alert </button>");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on('click', '#sub', function() {
      alert("Does it alert?");
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="add" name="sub">Add</button>
```