# .on('scroll') stops firing after usage of replaceWith() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-events

I'm trying to load more messages from database after I scroll to the top of the div:

```
$('#chatbox').on('scroll', function(){
    console.log($('#chatbox').scrollTop());
    if ($('#chatbox').scrollTop() == 0) {   
        var count = parseInt($('#chatroom-table tr').length) + 10;
        $.get('get_chatroom_messages/' + count, function(responseData) {
            $('#chatroom-div').replaceWith(responseData); 
        });
    }
});
```

This works great - once. After the `replaceWith()` is called for the first time, the `scroll()` method stops working. I tried rebinding the event, but with no success.

I thought that the `.on` method takes care of elements that are not yet created / are replaced.

EDIT:

I also tried this, but the event doesn't even fire at all then:

```
$('body').on('scroll', '#chatbox', function(){
    ....
});
```

EDIT2:

ehhh, I'm marking myself as a duplicate: [Events not registering after replaceWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770308/events-not-registering-after-replacewith)

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Are you perchance overwriting the element the eventlistener is attached to?

Comment: Yes, the element (#chatbox) is overwritten, but it is created again with same attributes. Does that mean that the event listener is also removed? I also tried binding the event to the 'body' and 'document' element, but the event doesn't fire at all then.

Comment: HOWEVER, I'm not sure how am I supposed to rebind the event after the replaceWith()?

Comment: @RokDolinar, do you mean that you tried event delegation?

Comment: That should answer your question! Yes, the eventlistener is removed or rather it is attached to an element no longer in the DOM.

Comment: @Jacob I will look into it. For now, I did a hackish solution: I added the event listener creator to the blade file - next to HTML. Now whenever the replaceWith() method is called, the javascript/jquery code is also replaced -> the event listener is thus created again. I guess this is ugly as hell, right?